# Happiness is Mandatory

Tags: code-golf, image-processing

If you're sad, that's *wrong*. We need to scrub out ALL sadness.

This is a sad face, for reference:

```
  ......  
  .S..S.  
 ........ 
 ...SS... 
..SS..SS..
.S......S.
 ........
```

Where `S` is a consistent pixel, `.` is any pixel other than `S`, and   is any pixel. Note that the sad face is not a perfect square, only the `.` should be considered. Theoretical sad face overlap in the corners is possible, but overwriting one sad face has a chance to eliminate the other, e.g. if it was in a `.` character and is overwritten with an `S`.

## Input

An image, in [any acceptable format](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9093/62402). I would recommend a color matrix.

## Output

The same image, but take all those *treasonous* sad faces and replace their `S` characters with randomized data. The data should be either random RGB values, or values taken from the palette of the image. You just need to have a nonzero probability of all outputs; you do not need to make it uniform.

## Rules

- `S` can be any pixel, as long as it's the same pixel throughout the formation.
- Remove ALL sad faces. If the removal makes a new sad face, then remove that too.
- You should only modify `S` pixels. Unauthorized modification of pixels is insubordination, punishable by disqualification.
- The shortest answer in bytes wins.

## Test Cases

These have one sad face each:

- [image]
- [image]

This has 2 sad faces, on the left and right:

[image]

This has 2 sad faces overlapping:

[image]

This has 2 sad faces, in the top-left and bottom-right; the bottom-left and top-right have `S` characters in the place of `.` characters:

[image]

Comment: Why not replace all pixels with white pixels?

Comment: @anatolyg because then it won't be replacing it with randomized data. also, if i make a sad face that's black-on-white and then run it through this program, it will still look like a sad face as long as enough of the randomized data is dark enough :p

Comment: @StephenLeppik doesn't this work? https://pastebin.com/T8mYQx8B To clarify: I meant overlap the square boundary, not the happy face itself

Comment: @Riker oh, yeah that would be acceptable.

Comment: @Riker it's open now; you can post your solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>339</s> <s>337</s> <s>331</s>  323 bytes

- Saved <s>two</s> <s>eight</s> <s>fifteen</s> sixteen bytes thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat).

```c
C,a,l,A,m,i,t,o,u,s;n(e,z,Z)int*e;{for(C=1;C;C+=i)for(C=s=0;s<Z;s++)for(u=0;u<z;u++)if(u>8&s>5)for(m=e[~-u+~-s*z],A=i=1;++A<4;)for(o=0;o<7;o++)for(t=0;t<10;t++)a=e[l=u+t-9+(s+o-6)*z],(o-1||t-3&&t-6)*(o-3||t<4|5<t)*(o-4||t<2|3<t&t<6|7<t)*(o-5||t-1&&t-8)?o>1|t>1&t<8&o<2|o>3&o<6|t&&t<9&&(i*=a-m):A<3?i*=a==m:i?e[l]=rand():e;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVRdU@owEH1uf0Xkzq1JmyKVT0lShvLkMw/O6PDQwSKdsY1D0wG0@NdxUxBQuei9cwOE3bNnz6ZJs2P3YTxerwc0pI@0TxMaU0UlzWnGUhzRZ3pL4lTZEXuZyBkeCI8N2MARMdm4maixjN@yzHFKJAc/588sBz@e4NzvWJnfLEOJiO5e3dx5dTP7eUT7IgYxx@nzBivjElIlbzO5lVLgK@7BBEAIyY8id5R75eDMkW6LaBEsXa8olFu3LKUh8Ovg80bR5Kp0G9q9LOpcWYq3ivYWbuosT2d1SE/6XqF8DwgdSwJZ@nX4bxUK4vzKsnBsi9BNSLfP6z1tC5F04x6saCRmYXqPSTdiq/WFbSJULQdC2hxW4avN6nZszOGwNDeG/pmaqcewesi1L8wkjFNMXkxDn8E1ndMpK210I2qLSTloAPtkGim@FhgidyNNN27od58dKTiY/0j6kZJWCU6Tgl254EjxkvRRIfj5moKD8kdJn4sfIX0t/rdbcJJkGis6F16bToXnETg209Cvuj7RJRzjkk/ZU64yXKkQutzeAx1cQHDB52wB2NMMkAmu/K51FqhCr@8WztKej8guk/2D6IsGxuJdDCQMuL5jIS4J5I6n4Qyfn51raSN6zCK0Cb6/g3sO@srZB38dBHdgD8CVuTLNCxsJIdBgGqYPUYaS8D7SgGkO8wcAFPpPl51fWlizlN8mcNU9C0uQkNClNK47QYcUxfE7D73g4NYTFKeZisJ7JCdICgFSSoh6AVMLpMEEAHpJy1el29CuZzV8BUWaVmcLN8s0T6fB@k7V6@Ld6k8uv1y/JcIzkZD9/n3X5j48zc92aS/@sR3WDrU@P4UJnW39Bg)